# Use java reflection to analyze Java project

Tags: java, reflection

I'm having an issue with java reflection.
How can I load a .java file or the whole project then analyze them?

input : .java code

output : analyzed class, method, relations between classes, attributes. v/v

Comment: What issues are you having? Any specific error message? Is your attempt to reflect resulting in finding properties that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing .java files is a lot more difficult than it sounds, as they are pure text and therefore requires textual analysis inorder to get something. A tool like PMD knows that and performs static code analysis on .java files.
https://pmd.github.io/

Analyzing .class files however is alot easier. For this task one need to create a custom class loader object (`URLClassLoader` should work) and use it to search and load all of the `Class` objects. Then one cause those objects' methods to get information on those classes. A tool that performs static code analysis on .class files is FindBugs.
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net

Hopefully this helps you bit